# Magnifier PopUp is not working..All file paths are correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I am trying to open a popup when user click on link using Magnifier PopUp but its not working. files are in correct order but it's not working.
**My console says:**

> Uncaught TypeError: window.$(...).magnificPopup is not a function

Here's my code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<a class="hello" href="imgs/work/1.jpg">clcik here to popup</a>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script>

$('.hello').magnificPopup({
    type: "image" // <== comma shouldn't be here since there is nothing to initialize after this
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: It says Uncaught TypeError: $(...).magnificPopup is not a function at new.html:16

Comment: Try to add a proper [DOCTYPE](http://tanalin.com/en/blog/2011/04/html5-doctype/). There is also a probability that the magnification plugin is intended for an older major version of jQuery.

Comment: added but still not working

Answer (score 2):

Not all of you filepaths are correct - you are using `\` instead of `/`

So this -

```
<a class="hello" href="imgs\work\1.jpg">clcik here to popup</a>
```

Should be -

```
<a class="hello" href="imgs/work/1.jpg">clcik here to popup</a>
```

And this -

```
<script src="js\jquery.js"></script>
```

Should be -

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:** Upon reading the documentation (following a quick Google search), it appears that you missed the step on **[Initializing popup](https://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html)**

You need to add this:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
});
```

Comment: still not working.. now i tried jquery cdn and changed the paths but still not solved..